# Last Row in Excel VBA Evaluate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, evaluate

I am using the below code:

```
Sub Evaluation_Formula()
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        i = .Evaluate("MIN(IF((LEFT($B$1:$B$89,5)*1)=C1,$B$1:$B$89,""""))")
        .Range("F3").Value2 = i
    End With
End Sub
```

However, the formula is limited to B89, how can I use Last Row in Column B in the formula ?

Comment: You know how to use an esoteric function like `evaluate` but can't find last row O.o

Comment: [Find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) the last row and store it in a variable like `lastrow` then: `i = Evaluate("MIN(IF((LEFT($B$1:$B$" & lastrow & ",5)*1)=C1,$B$1:$B$" & lastrow & ",""""))")`. Edit there is no `.` before `Evaluate`

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you very much, I do know LR thingy but just couldn't understand how to use it in, as FindWindow said: esoteric, evaluate formula.     Sub Evaluation_Formula_w_LR()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        i = Evaluate("MIN(IF((LEFT($B$1:$B$" & LR & ",5)*1)=C1,$B$1:$B$" & LR & ",""""))")
        .Range("F10").Value2 = i
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Yes, it works *like* a charm. How can I add code in replies here on SF btw ? I couldn't post my new code :( properly

Comment: You can't add them to the comments,  either add it as and answer or back on the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will post proper code:

```
Sub Evaluation_Formula_w_LR()
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    i = Evaluate("MIN(IF((LEFT($B$1:$B$" & LR & ",5)*1)=C1,$B$1:$B$" & LR & ",""""))")
    .Range("F10").Value2 = i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I made a little edit.  When you can mark it as correct.

Comment: May I know how to do that please ? :)

Comment: Eventually there will be a green check mark beside the answer.  click on it.

Comment: btw, the empty quotes in the latter half of the IF formula are completely unnecessary and only serve to confuse the issue at hand. You can mark a self-answered post as the accepted answer after 48 hours.

Comment: Which quotes you are talking about ? ...LR & ",""""))")...If I remove two of them, it gives me Type Mismatch error.

Comment: The Third criteria in the if statement is not needed, If it is false then it is going to through an error regardless of the third criteria.  So `Evaluate("MIN(IF((LEFT($B$1:$B$" & LR & ",5)*1)=C1,$B$1:$B$" & LR & "))")`

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thanks for your help Scott and Jeeped :)

Answer (score 3):

For all intents and purposes you are really only concerned with the last number in column B, not specifically the last row. To do that in a worksheet formula you would use something like this array formula.

```
=MIN(IF(--LEFT(B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )),5)=C1, B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))
```

That can translate into your VBA [Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) like the following.

```
Sub Evaluation_Formula()
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        i = .Evaluate("MIN(IF(--LEFT(B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )),5)=C1, B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))")
        .Range("F3").Value2 = i
    End With
End Sub
```

The **double unary** (aka *double-minus* or `--`) does the same job as multiplying the text result from the [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22) by 1. There is no need to pass a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) in as the FALSE is sufficient for non-matches in the IF function. Since you are evaluating text into a formula, there is no need for the `$` absolute markers.

Keep the `.` in `.Evaluate` or add the worksheet name to the cell references in the formula. Without it you run the risk of evaluating another worksheet's B1:B89 and C1 cells if **Sheet1** does not hold the workbook's [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Aaahhh lovely....thanks a million Jeeped, that's one comprehensive answer. God Bless You :)

Comment: @StarShines - and thank YOU for asking a decent question that showed both research and effort on your part.